# jsp(java) coding about rolling dice

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to display the output after the user input the number for rolling the dice and I can't call the computation i put in the aligator tag (<% %>). How will I do it?

this is my code:

```
<body>

    <p>Note: Make sure the numbers are among the following: 4, 6, 8, 10, and 20.</p>
    <form id="diceForm" name="diceForm" action="">
    <label>Enter your number here:</label>
    <input type="number" name="dicenum" required='required' placeholder="Enter a number among 4, 6, 8, 10, and 20...">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <% int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dicenum")); 
    if (num == 4)
        num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*4);
    else if (num == 6)
        num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*6);
    else if (num == 8)
        num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*8);
    else if (num == 10)
        num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*10);
    else if (num == 20)
        num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*20);
    else
        num = 0;
    %>
    <%= (num == 0)? "The number you've entered is out of range.": num %>
    </body>
```

Comment: What are you going to do about the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't check whether request parameter is null or not during very first load of jsp and server might generates exception. Replace your scriptlet code by following one :

```
<% 
  if(request.getParameter("dicenum") != null) {
%>  

<% 
int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dicenum")); 
if (num == 4)
    num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*4);
else if (num == 6)
    num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*6);
else if (num == 8)
    num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*8);
else if (num == 10)
    num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*10);
else if (num == 20)
    num = 1+(int)(Math.random()*20);
else
    num = 0;
%>
<%= (num == 0)? "The number you've entered is out of range.": num %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your first request, when page loads there is no `dicenum` parameter in request, unless you load your page this way :`http://localhost:8070/../page.jsp?decinum=20` manually adding request parameter to URL.

When user submits the form via `<input type="submit" value="submit">`, as your request type is `GET`(which is default), request parameter `dicenum` gets appended to URL, thus forming  URL `http://localhost:8070/../page.jsp?decinum=value`, where `value` will be substituted with the value entered in the form.

Therefore on the first request(first page load), when user did not submit any form values yer, there is no request parameter `dicenum` and therefore you are getting NullPointerException in this line

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dicenum"));
```

because it interprets to `Integer.parseInt(null)`, as `request.getParameter("dicenum"` interprets to `null`

You need to guard against NullPointerException, surrounding your Java statements in block, so if request parameter `dicenum` is `null` Java won't evaluate surrounded block.

```
 <% 
  if(request.getParameter("dicenum") != null) {
  %>  

  ... your Java statements

   <% }  %>
```

---

Another observation is that you are unnecessary repeating yourself in `if... else blocks` which can be rewritten as

```
if (num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 10 || num == 20){
        num = 1 + (Math.random()*num);
```

Again, this is a just suggestion

Complete code would be :

```
<body>

    <p>Note: Make sure the numbers are among the following: 4, 6, 8, 10, and 20.</p>
    <form id="diceForm" name="diceForm" action="">
    <label>Enter your number here:</label>
    <input type="number" name="dicenum" required='required' placeholder="Enter a number among 4, 6, 8, 10, and 20...">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

  <% 
  if(request.getParameter("dicenum") != null) {   // Opening curly braces for NPE guard
  %>  

<% 
int num = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dicenum")); 

    if (num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 10 || num == 20){
        num = 1 + (Math.random()*num);
  } else {
     num = 0;
  }

%>
<%= (num == 0)? "The number you've entered is out of range.": num %>
<% } %>                         // Closing curly braces for NPE guard

</body>
```